# How would I go about looping a specific date in a month in VB for excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba, date

IM trying to pull every instance of Wednesday for the month of April

and have it spit out into an excel cell, but im having trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=42):

```
Public Function FloatingHoliday(xYear As Integer, xMonth As Integer, _
    xDay As Integer,  xNumber As Integer) 

    FloatingHoliday = DateSerial(xYear, xMonth, _
        (8 - Weekday(DateSerial(xYear, xMonth, 1),  _ 
        (xDay + 1) Mod 8)) + ((xNumber - 1) * 7)) 

End Function
```

In a blank cell in the workbook, type =floatingholiday(2004,11,5,4) where 2004 is the year, 11 is the month (November), 5 is the Day (Thursday) {Sunday = 1, Monday = 2 etc.}, and 4 is the nth day of that month, in this case we want the 4th Thursday of November 2004 (Thanksgiving).